# Firestore overriding data even with merge option

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following method which connects to Firestore as expected and adds data if there is existing data.

But if I add an empty object it clears out all my data. I do not want it to over ride in such instances, I just want it to leave my data as it is. Is this possible?

Since the value here is {} it clears out existing data. I want my existing data to remain not get deleted.

```
  Future initialiseUserData(String uid) async {
    return await collection.doc(uid).set({
      'my_list' : {}
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }
```

No issue if I actually have data, meaning it adds on data. Not delete existing data as expected.

```
  Future initialiseUserData(String uid) async {
    return await collection.doc(uid).set({
      'my_list' : {
        "key" : "value"
      }
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
  }
```

Comment: you need read it, and append with new data, if you write same field

Comment: To look into this, can you please provide a screenshot of the data before and after you run the code?